# How do people model photorealistic products?

Tags: modeling

[image]

To accurately recreate a product, do people use 3D scans? or perhaps they request for / make their own blueprints to get the accurate measurements? right now, I'm trying to model a gaming mouse and I'm facing a lot of difficulty, I was wondering if there are easier ways to achieve photorealism rather than model off orthographic reference images from google.

Comment: IMHO this question is not opinion based because there are a finite number of methods and list each with a brief explanation would satisfy the question without offering opinions.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: People do any of 1) Get the cad files from the product designer; 2) 3D scan; 3) manually measure perhaps drawing blueprints or just committing measurements to their model; 4) model from photographs that are imported into the scene; 5) model from photographs viewed outside the scene; 6) model by examining the actual object; 7) guess; or some combination ov the above.

Comment: @MartyFouts this was the summary I was looking for, thank you. Hope this question will be reopened

Answer (score 0):

these mouses are mostly designed related to human hand organic shape , also you must consider many other parameters such as a computer mouse features and functionalities ( if you're modeling for production)  , afterall you must get help from your imaginations , also you need to know about topology and study about that , which will help you to better understand how a three dimensional model get formed , in that way you'll not even need a blueprint to work with (but if you want to get the idea you need the blueprint , cause blueprints don't do any magic)